# carrierwave throws "stack level too deep" error on file upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave

i have a weired problem and don't now how to debug further...

if i upload an file with my html form i get:

```
SystemStackError (stack level too deep):
```

the trace is:

```
Started POST "/global/accounts/82" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-07-27 10:28:03 +0200
  Processing by Global::AccountsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"tAf/cGPjW+uGgdl6J7t+IZgGsNKkVDLCCWYMFdtQd7g=", "account"=>{"logo_cache"=>"", "shortcut_icon"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x0000010632daa0 @original_filename="18677_265409985796_708130796_4889342_5500573_n.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"account[shortcut_icon]\"; filename=\"18677_265409985796_708130796_4889342_5500573_n.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n", @tempfile=#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20110727-3683-1yazc7m>>, "shortcut_icon_cache"=>""}, "commit"=>"Einstellungen speichern", "member"=>{"cancel"=>:get}, "id"=>"82"}
  User Load (1.1ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 261 LIMIT 1
  Account Load (0.8ms)  SELECT `accounts`.* FROM `accounts` WHERE `accounts`.`id` = 82 LIMIT 1
  SQL (2.0ms)  describe `roles_users`
  Role Load (3.8ms)  SELECT `roles`.* FROM `roles` INNER JOIN `roles_users` ON `roles`.id = `roles_users`.role_id WHERE `roles`.`name` = 'admin' AND (`roles_users`.user_id = 261 ) LIMIT 1
  Account Load (1.9ms)  SELECT `accounts`.* FROM `accounts` WHERE `accounts`.`subdomain` = '***' LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.6ms)  SELECT 1 FROM `accounts` WHERE (LOWER(`accounts`.`subdomain`) = LOWER('***')) AND (`accounts`.id <> 82) LIMIT 1
  AREL (0.5ms)  UPDATE `accounts` SET `shortcut_icon` = 'aadf09e05f4db4124c62bfb9340aa9bd.jpg', `updated_at` = '2011-07-27 08:28:08' WHERE `accounts`.`id` = 82
  Account Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `accounts`.* FROM `accounts` WHERE `accounts`.`id` = 82 LIMIT 1
  SQL (1.2ms)  ROLLBACK
Completed   in 2831ms

SystemStackError (stack level too deep):
```

analysing the trace, it seems that the file is uploaded and written to the DB:

```
 AREL (0.5ms)  UPDATE `accounts` SET `shortcut_icon` = 'aadf09e05f4db4124c62bfb9340aa9bd.jpg', `updated_at` = '2011-07-27 08:28:08' WHERE `accounts`.`id` = 82
```

but after that it throws the error....

testing carrierwave in the rails console:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180> path = "/Users/kalle/Desktop/button.png"
ruby-1.9.2-p180> u = Account.last
ruby-1.9.2-p180> u.logo = File.open(path)
 => #<File:/Users/kalle/Desktop/button.png> 
ruby-1.9.2-p180> u.save!
 => true
```

works fine!

well, i have a file upload @ another model, so the carrierwave installation works fine (similar uploader).

testing the html form **without the file filed**, it works fine!

so:

- Form works without file field
- carrierwave file upload works in the console
- different model, similar carrierwave uploader/config => works!

**how can i debug further ?**

thanks for any help!

Rails 3.0.7/ruby-1.9.2-p180/carrierwave (0.5.3)

EDIT:
seems that it happens only on the update action.

controller:

```
def update
  if current_account.update_attributes(params[:account])
    flash[:notice] = 'Successfully updated account.'
    redirect_to global_settings_path
  else
    render :action => 'edit'
  end
end
```

Comment: Stack Level too deep means that you have an infinite loop somewhere.  You don't have a method that calls itself somewhere in the update action do you?

Comment: nope, that was the first thing i checked. the model/controller is pretty basic. i realised that the update action with an file upload does not work in the other models too. so i'm pretty sure it's a carrierwave "bug".

Comment: I'm guessing an ActiveRecord callback may be responsible. Can you post your Account model?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem.
When I called photo.url it throwed a "stack level to deep error".

It seemed I had the following code in my PhotoUploader:

```
  def url
    filename = self.to_s
    content_type = File.mime_type?(filename)    
    ext = {
      'image/png'  => :png,
      'image/jpg'  => :jpg,
      'image/jpeg' => :jpg,
      'image/gif'  => :gif

    }[content_type]
    ext ||= :jpg

    { :id => model.id, :version => version_name, :format => ext }    
  end
```

This code seemed to work fine in carrierwave 0.5.8.
I updated to 0.6.2 and since it failed.

The problem is I'm calling self.to_s. As I found out in the carrierwave code:
to_s is implemented like this:

```
  def to_s
    url || ''
  end
```

By changing self.to_s to self.file the problem was solved

```
  def url
    filename = self.file
    # ... rest of the code ..
  end
```