# Carrier Wave hangs on update when no upload is provided

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

I am using Carrierwave in a fairly standard way to manage the uploading of image files such as logos, posters and user images.

I am finding that I can upload an image no problem on new or edit. I am using Heroku and hence need to use ASW S3 on production and staging. I have a switch in my uploader file to handle this.

```
if ['development', 'test'].include?(Rails.env)
  storage :file
else
  storage :fog
end
```

This works great on dev, but when I switch to production if a user goes to edit a record from the model without a file attached the whole thing comes to a grinding halt and times out.

I can also replicate this on development by changing the storage to `:fog`.

I have searched and only really come across this one that is remotely close to what I am seeing: [6841798](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841798/carrierwave-throws-stack-level-too-deep-error-on-file-upload)

Hopefully someone has seen this before and can shed some light.

Comment: Please provide your controller and view code.

Answer (score 0):

@benjamin

Thanks for the follow up.

Here is a [gist](https://gist.github.com/lukebyrne/5095502) of all the code.

As I can tell this only really has an issue when I go to update the project without a poster.

If I change the development storage (image_uploader.rb line 16) to :file then it works fine locally.

Also if I comment out the forms (edit.html.haml lines 12-23) then it also works fine.

This seems to be inline with the sentiments [from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841798/carrierwave-throws-stack-level-too-deep-error-on-file-upload), however I cannot work out what the deal is. My guess is that there is some callback that is being performed by Carrier Wave when you are trying to upload to Fog, and if there is no file mounted it gets into an infinite loop somewhere.

Hope you me be able to shed some light.

Cheers,

Luke

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to fix this issue by removing the 
`attr_accessible remote_poster_url` from the model and also commenting out the

```
= f.input :remote_poster_url, label: 'Add a poster from a URL'
```

This now allows me to handle all cases of adding a project that has no poster, editing that posters info again, adding a poster and then updating more info without it hanging.

Hope this can help someone else who may come across this issue.